# I'm struggling with multiple AND/OR conditions within this query. Am I close or is there an easier solution?

Tags: sql

Within a table of data, there are three fields that have a user's country. For example, suzyq@email.com has a shipping country, a country, and a country_sel all of which may or may not be completely filled. There are also different variations of data that live within these fields (US, U.S, USA, CA, CAN).

Data table example:

```
| email   | shipping| country  | country_sel |
|:----:   | :------:| :-----:  |   :-----:   |
|1@ex.com |   US    |    US    |     USA     |
|2@ex.com |   US    |          |      US     |
|3@ex.com |   CA    |    CA    |      US     |
|4@ex.com |   AU    |    AU    |             |
```

The goal is to select ONLY users that have variations of US, U.S, USA within one, two, or all three of the these fields, like 1@ex.com and 2@ex.com.
Note : Two of these fields may be Null

And I need to *exclude* all users that do not have any US, U.S, USA variations, like 4@ex.com.

I also need to *exclude* any users that have a mix of US, U.S, USA variations with non-US data. Like 3@ex.com example above.

The closest I've gotten was using the EXCEPT clause below, but it's excluding a set of users I DO need. There is also one or two users slipping in that are not US. I've tried this query multiple times changing up AND and ORs, but can't seem to get this right. Please any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    SELECT email, shipping, country, country_sel
    FROM table
    WHERE purchased = 'True'
    AND ((shipping IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR shipping IS NULL)
    OR (country IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR country IS NULL)
    OR (country_sel IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR country_sel IS NULL))
    EXCEPT
    SELECT email, shipping, country, country_sel
    FROM table
    WHERE purchased = 'True'
    AND ((shipping IS NOT NULL AND shipping NOT IN ('US','U.S','USA'))
    AND (country IS NOT NULL AND country NOT IN ('US','U.S','USA'))
    OR (country_sel IS NOT NULL AND country_sel NOT IN ('US','U.S','USA')));
```

Comment: You may need to restate your goal; 'select ONLY users that have all variations of US, U.S, USA within each of the three fields, like 1@ex.com and 2@ex.com.' 2@ex.com has no value(assuming NULL) in `country` field. That is different then what you state.

Comment: You are correct. I've rephrased the goal. The goal is to pull all users that have US, U.S, USA in any or all of the three fields (shipping, country, and/or country_sel). And exclude users that have non-US, U.S, USA values in any combination of those fields, like 3@ex.com and 4@ex.com in the example data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for -

```
SELECT email, shipping, country, country_sel
    FROM table
    WHERE purchased = 'True'
    AND ((shipping IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR shipping IS NULL)
    AND (country IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR country IS NULL)
    AND (country_sel IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR country_sel IS NULL))
    -- above would pull even all three as blank (NULL); so, adding below filter
    AND (shipping IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR 
         country IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR
         country_sel IN ('US','U.S','USA'));
```

Also, note you had used 'USA; instead of 'USA'
You would need to fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email, shipping, country, country_sel
    FROM table
    WHERE purchased = 'True'
    AND ((shipping IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR shipping IS NULL)
    AND (country IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR country IS NULL)
    AND (country_sel IN ('US','U.S','USA') OR country_sel IS NULL))
    AND ( shipping IS Not Null OR country IS Not Null OR country_sel IS Not Null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it looks like my original question was not phrased correctly. I've updated what the goal is for this. Yes, this solution does pull all fields with US value, but I'm looking for fields that have a combination of US values. Also, excluding any combination of US values and non-US values.

Comment: HI @LinaDee I reread your goal and don't understand why this query does not work, it works with your samples. PLease add an other sample that does not work with this sql.

Answer (score 0):

Using lateral and except

```
select  email, shipping, country, country_sel
from  tbl
cross join lateral (
    select count(*) n
    from (
       select * 
          from (values (shipping),(country),(country_sel)) t1(c)
          where c is not null
       except 
       select * 
       from (values ('US'),('U.S'),('USA')) t2(c)
    ) t
 ) t
 where t.n = 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dc99134a8d30c4599057291c55eb34c4)

Answer (score 0):

One method is a `lateral join` to count the number of non-US values:

```
SELECT email, shipping, country, country_sel
FROM table t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt_non_us
      FROM (VALUES (shipping), (country), (country_sel)) v(country)
      WHERE v.country NOT IN ('US', 'U.S', 'USA')
     ) c
WHERE purchased = 'True' AND c.cnt_non_us = 0;
```